# EF include-query turns out faulty, inner exception is null

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I've built quite an extenxive EF query that's turning out to be faulty. Where and why seems to be impossible to track down because my innerexception just returns null. I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction. I built the query with [this open on my second monitor.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1)

```
var databaseRequirementVersions = context.RequirementVersions
            .Include(x => x.Requirement)
            .Include(x => x.RequirementDetails)
            .Include(x => x.TaggedValueRequirementCouplers)
            .Include(x => x.TaggedValueRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.TaggedValueVersion))
            .Include(x => x.TaggedValueRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.TaggedValueVersion.TaggedValue))
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers)
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.ConnectorVersion))
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.ConnectorVersion.Connector))
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.ConnectorVersion.ConnectorDetails))
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.ConnectorVersion.TaggedValueConnectorCouplers))
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.ConnectorVersion.TaggedValueConnectorCouplers.Select(a => a.TaggedValueVersion)))
            .Include(x => x.ConnectorRequirementCouplers.Select(y => y.ConnectorVersion.TaggedValueConnectorCouplers.Select(a => a.TaggedValueVersion.TaggedValue)))
            .Where(x => x.Requirement.Guid == element.ElementGUID);
```

Quick rundown of the database;
RequirementVersions always has 1 Requirement (Requirement can have multiple versions)
RequirementVersions always has 1 RequirementDetails
RequirementVersions has multiple TaggedValueRequirementCouplers (coupler-table)
RequirementTaggedValueVersion has multiple TaggedValueRequirementCouplers (coupler-table)
RequirementTaggedValueVersion always has 1 RequirementTaggedValue (RequirementTaggedValue can have multiple versions)

RequirementVersions has multiple ConnectorRequirementCouplers (coupler-table)
ConnectorVersion has multiple ConnectorRequirementCouplers (coupler-table)
ConnectorVersion always has 1 Connector (connector can have multiple versions)
ConnectorVersion always has 1 ConnectorDetails
ConnectorVersion has multiple ConnectorTaggedValueCouplers (coupler-table)
ConnectorTaggedValueVersion has multiple ConnectorTaggedValueCouplers (coupler-table)
ConnectorTaggedValueVersion has 1 ConnectorTaggedValue (ConnectorTaggedValue can have multiple ConnectorTaggedValueVersions)

Exception:
[image]
The stacktrace starts from MoreLinq `MaxBy<>` when just below the include statement it tries to issue the following line of code;

```
var MyList = new List<RequirementVersion>();
MyList.Add(databaseRequirementVersions?.MaxBy(x => x.Version));
```

What I have done to come to the conclusion my `.Include` is broken;
When I commented out (`//`) all `.Include`'s going deeper than the 2nd layer (so anything going past `y.` - meaning `y.ConnectorVersion` works, but `y.ConnectorVersion.Connector`, or (hypothetically) `y.ConnectorVersion.Select(z => z.Connector)` do not work) the query was accepted.

As I can't seem to figure this one out by myself with the tools available, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction..

**Edit:** @Evk wanted me to change the `MaxBy<>`-statement to make sure it was not causing the problem itself, so here's the new (same?) exception;
[image]

Comment: what a mess. complete nightmare to maintain and debug.

Comment: Start with simple checks: Enable database logs (context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine or something). Remove "?" here > "databaseRequirementVersions?". Replace MaxBy with FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Also check InnerException. What does it say

Comment: @MarkHomer thanks for the constructive feedback. Any reasons as to why and how I could make it more happy?

Comment: @Evk `context` does not have a `Database` property, the `?` is there to prevent an exception if the returned list is empty and `MaxBy<>` does something very different than `FirstOrDefault()` .. I like the logs idea, I'll try and search for a way around

Comment: @AndreyBorisko even the title answers that question ..

Comment: That is not to fix a problem, just to diagnose what exactly causes it. That is why I ask to remove ? and replace max with another statement - to see if it will still throw or not. As for Database property, that means its not DbContext object, then tell us what is it.

Comment: @Evk it is a DbContext-object, but it's been 'hombe-built' by a colleague of mine (I looked into it and the interface did not grant get-acces to the DbContext, so I wrote that in, to discover the DbContext-class has no 'Log' kept anywhere). The `?.MaxBy<>` is not te source of the problem, it's what's discovering the problem. Because, as I said, when I comment out the trouble-causing lines from the `.Include`-statement, it runs over the `?.MaxBy<>` without issue.

Comment: Well let's first see the logs (this property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Database.Log).

Comment: By the way, MoreLinq works with IEnumerables, not IQueryables, and so is client-side. What that means is your MaxBy will first pull everything into memory and then will find max element _in memory_, it will not perform MAX query over database and you might thought. So good first thing to do is still get rid of MaxBy (and in general of MoreLinq in database linq queries), though it's indeed is not related to the problem you now have.

Comment: @Evk main post has a screenshot of the `.FirstOrDefault()`-testrun, logs seem to return `Null`. Trying different things now

Comment: Logs cannot "return null". You need to set some log handler (like context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine or analog for your case). And then watch the console (or other output you have) for generated sql statements. Or you mean there are nothing in logs?

Comment: @Evk I'm running through the code with breakpoints, so right before it hits the faulty statement I have a line that says `var log = this.context.Log();` where `.Log()` in the context returns the `DbContext.Database.Log();` (just extends the call, basically). `var log` is said as null. Looking on the MSDN-page, I'm probably not writing to the log. Trying to figure out how to do so at the right time(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did to come to my answer;
by including the following line of code in my DbContext-constructor;

```
var logPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"Folder\DatabaseLog.log");
this.DbContext.Database.Log = (s) => File.AppendAllText(logPath, s);
```

I managed to create quite an extensive log on what database-communication takes place. It displayed where and why an error occured. The actual error does not make much difference in terms of the answer (a typo in a column/table -reference), but the logging played a huge role in finding it;

much thank you's to @Evk for the logging-suggestion